# Restrict internet connection for wps-office on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, internet, wps-office

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 3546**.
I want to restrict internet access to *WPS Office 2019*. I installed it using a *`.deb`* file downloaded from [here](https://linux.wps.com/). I want to **completely restrict internet access only for this app**. I don't want network problems elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this.
I uninstalled the `.deb` app, and installed it's **flatpak** instead! Then I installed **`Flatseal`** and disabled network access for WPS Office.

Works like a charm !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [firejail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/firejail.1.html).

```
firejail --net=none <application>
```

Firejail offers a ton of choices, including rate-limiting on a per-application basis. It is also a sandboxing application. It has a ton of great features.

```
sudo apt install firejail
man firejail
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will want to use [trickle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/trickle.1.html)

```
trickle -u 0 -d 0 {application/service}
```

Be sure to change `{application/service}` to the application or service that you want to restrict.